# VB.NET Code for datagridview to textbox in one line

Tags: vb.net

How can I code this in vb.net. I want to show all data in textbox area

datagridview data

```
   name    purchase   Group            
   vince   26         G1                  
   jenny   28         G1                  
   david   31         G1
```

Expected Output
what will be the code for this result in vb.net?

```
vince-26-G1, jenny-28-G1, david-31-G1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
dim myString as string = ""
For Each dataR as datagridviewrow in datagridview1.rows
mystring = mystring + dataR.cells(0).value.tostring + "-" + dataR.cells(1).value.tostring + "-" + dataR.cells(2).value.tostring + ",  "

Next

textbox1.text = mystring
```

Untested, but that's about what you're looking to do